# What is the purpose of @Singleton on a function (Hilt)

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

In Android Hilt, you can apply the @Singleton annotation to a function like this:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object SomeModule {
    
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSomething(): String {
        return "Hi there"
    }
}
```

I don't understand what the purpose of using a singleton on a function accomplishes. A class that has the @Singleton means that an instance of the class only exists once. But you cannot create instances of functions, so I don't see the point.

Answer (score 10):

`@Singleton` is called Scope and by default, all bindings in Hilt are unscoped. This means that each time your app requests the binding, Hilt creates a new instance of the needed type. For example in your case each time you request a String a new string is going to be created.

But when you add `@Singleton` annotation you said that the scope of this instance is singleton so it's going to provide the same instance each time you request a String.

Unlike `SingletonComponent` which is a component, it decide where you can use that module, so if you change it to `ViewModelComponent` for example you will be able to use that module only from `ViewModel` and it's lifecycle is going to be related to the ViewModel lifecycle.

You can take a look here for more information: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#generated-components

Take a look at this example:

instead of just providing a static string try to provide some random number:

```
@Provides
fun provideString(): String {
    return (1..100).random().toString()
}
```

Without `@Singleton` when you inject String in different classes in your App you will get different results because each time hilt is going to run the code inside `provideString` function so it's going to return a new instance of String ( that's what I mean by providing a new instance ).

Now add `@Singleton`:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideString(): String {
    return (1..100).random().toString()
}
```

You will notice that the provided String is the same across your app so `provideString` is called once and the result is saved so hilt is returning that saved instance of String every time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "instance" when it comes to functions. There is no such thing as "function instances". Only classes have instances. A function only exists once for each class instance.

Comment: You see it as a function but Hilt is going to generate some code and it is going to save the object returned from that function, so if you add @Singleton hilt is going to call that function once and save the result of that call and provide it anytime you request that result, but if you don't add it hilt is not going to save that result and each time it's going to provide a new result.

Comment: @Johann answer updated, I added an example take a look at it and you can try it

Comment: Before you posted your comment above, I single stepped through the Hilt generated code and discovered (as you just mentioned) that the value returned by the function gets cached internally by Hilt and will return the same value if @Singleton is used. So the word "singleton" doesn't refer to the function itself but the returned value. This is more like Kotlin's lazy operator that executes the lambda once and caches the lambda's return value and returns that value any time the variable is accessed again. They should have named it Lazy or Cached and not Singleton.

Comment: @Johann yes exactly try the example above and you will see it in action

Comment: Interesting, isn't `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` sufficient to denote all provided instances from a module as singleton? This was my initial understanding, please correct me why that's not the case.

Comment: @VCODE `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` decides from where you can access this module, so `SingletonComponent` means that you can access this module from the whole app and `ViewModelComponent` for example means that you can use that module only from a ViewModel

Answer (score -1):

Functions can be singletons just like classes , It will assure only one instance will be created .
Normally multiple calls of same function will be stacked , and performed one by one , while in a singleton function  , last call will overwrite the previous one   .so if you called it 10 times in a loop , no instances of the calls will be stacked in the memory.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no support for multiple instances of a funciton in the Kotlin language. Don't know where you came up with that idea, but it has no foundation in Kotlin.

Comment: Since Kotlin is based on JVM  , it has a  JVM memory behavior  , So when you set @Singlton annotation to a function , its call  , including memory allocation for its arguments  and their consuming , will follow the singleton pattern.